# IndexError: index out of bounds

Tags: python, arrays, syntax-error, pde, odeint

I am new to Python and appreciate any constructive feedback.
My task is to solve a PDE using ODEINT where my spatial grid is defined as follows:

```
L = [8.0, 4.0, 8.0]   # Lenght of spatial zones 
dN = 1.0e2            # Number of grid points
N = [int(l*dN) for l in L] # Gives number of grid points over each spatial zone
```

By using the ODEINT function believe I must define an array of zeros for my solution, and an array of time points. I am struggling to find out how I write the correct size for the array's. I have tried:

```
dydt = np.zeros(shape=N) # For solution
t = np.linspace(0, 2, 2000) # for time
```

### But that gives me the error message:

IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     70 t = np.linspace(0, 2, lN)
     71 
---> 72 U = odeint(numeric, y0, t, args=(h, D1, D2, N))
     73 
     74 Fexit = U/Np

/Users/severinlangeberg/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py in odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, full_output, ml, mu, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin, ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords, printmessg)
    213     output = _odepack.odeint(func, y0, t, args, Dfun, col_deriv, ml, mu,
    214                              full_output, rtol, atol, tcrit, h0, hmax, hmin,
--> 215                              ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
    216     if output[-1] < 0:
    217         warning_msg = _msgs[output[-1]] + " Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information."

in numeric(y, t, h, D1, D2, N)
     39 
     40     for i in [N[0] + 1]: # 800 = special 2, must be from begining of N[1]
---> 41         dydt[i] = D2 * (-3*y[i] + 4*y[i + 1] - y[i + 2] / h**2) # pluss
     42 
     43     for i in range (N[0] + 2, N[0] + N[1] - 2): # from 801 to 1197, or 2 to 397

IndexError: index 801 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 800

```
Which seems to come from my loops:
# ODE setup
def numeric(y, t, h, D1, D2, N):

    dydt = np.zeros((N))

    # End grid points
    dydt[0] = 0
    dydt[-1] = 0


    # Inner grid points
    for i in range (1, N[0] - 2): # 1 to 797
        dydt[i] = D1 * (y[i - 1] - 2*y[i]+ y[i + 1]) / h**2 # range i = j - 1

    for i in [N[0] - 2]: # 798 = special 1
        dydt[i] =  D1 * (-3*y[i] - 4*y[i - 1] + y[i - 2]) / h**2 # minus

    for i in [N[0] - 1]: # 799 = unknown, and last index in N[0]
        dydt[i] = ((D1*(-3*y[i] + 4*y[i + 1] - y[i + 2])) - (D2*(-3*y[i] - 4*y[i - 1] + y[i - 2])))

    for i in [N[0] + 1]: # 800 = special 2, must be from begining of N[1]
        dydt[i] = D2 * (-3*y[i] + 4*y[i + 1] - y[i + 2] / h**2) # pluss

    for i in range (N[0] + 2, N[0] + N[1] - 2): # from 801 to 1197, or 2 to 397
        dydt[i] = D2 * (y[i - 1] - 2*y[i] + y[i + 1]) / h**2 # range

    for i in [N[0] + N[1] - 1]: # at 1198, or 398 = special 3
        dydt[i] = D2 * (-3*y[i] - 4*y[i - 1] + y[i - 2]) / h**2 # range

    for i in [N[0] + N[1]]: # 1199, or 399 = unknown
        dydt[i] = ((D1*(-3*y[i] + 4*y[i + 1] - y[i + 2])) - (D2*(-3*y[i] - 4*y[i - 1] + y[i - 2])))

    for i in [N[0] + N[1] + 1]: # at 1200, or 1 = special 4
        dydt[i] =  D1 * (-3*y[i + 1] + 4*y[i + 2] - y[i + 3] / h**2)  # pluss

    for i in range (N[0] + N[1] + 2, N[0] + N[1] + N[2] - 1): # 1202 to 1999
        dydt[i] = D1 * (y[i - 1] - 2*y[i]+ y[i + 1]) / h**2 # range

    return dydt
```

Comment: please share only relevant part of code where you are facing problem. Your question should be concise so that it saves our time while answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look, it seems the problem is the for loop, instead of using `for i in [N[0]]`, are you sure it's not `for i in range(N[0])`?

`for i in [N[0]]` is rather redundant because the list only contains one element, ie. `N[0]`, so the list of size **800** becomes out of index when you try to seek `dydt[800]` <-- as the max index is `799`.

Like so:

```
In [9]: N
Out[9]: [800, 400, 800]

In [10]: for i in [N[0]]:  # ie. i == N[0] == 800
   ....:     dydt[i] = 0
   ....:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-04daa45ec403> in <module>()
      1 for i in [N[0]]:  # ie. i == N[0] == 800
----> 2     dydt[i] = 0
      3 

IndexError: index 800 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 800

In [11]: for i in range(N[0]):
   ....:     dydt[i] = 0
   ....:
```

Comment: Yes, I want to specify that in the point N[0], dydt[i] = 0. That's why I wrote "for i in[N[0]]". Do you have any tips on what I could have done?

Comment: @GSEL, if you want to assign the last index of dydt as 0, it should be `dydt[N[0] - 1] = 0` instead.

Comment: Thanks! So if the last element of N[0] is N[0 - 1], that means N[0] does not exist? 

What I wanted to do was to divide the spatial grid for my PDE into three zones and applying extra boundary conditions at the end and beginning of each zone. The result should all be in one matrix, but from the way I have previously done tells me I have a solution matrix that consist of three columns instead of one. Is this correct, and do you know if it will be a problem when solving with ODEINT?

Comment: @GSEL, I'm not good at PDE or any mathematical theories... but judging from what you're trying to say, is that possible that [laplace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.laplace.html) is what you are looking for? And for the boundary values, I have a google search and this may be interested to you [Constructing discrete Laplacian via sparse matrix](http://erg.biophys.msu.ru/wordpress/archives/706)

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [8.0, 4.0, 8.0] 
dN = 1.0e2 
N = [int(l*dN) for l in L] # create array [800, 400, 800] 

dydt = np.zeros(shape=N) # create 3 dimensional matrix 
                         # 1d has size 800 (from 0 to 799 including)
                         # 2d has size 400 (from 0 to 399 including)
                         # 3d same as 1st
```

In this code:

```
for i in[N[0]]: 
    dydt[i] = 0 # Unknown point
```

I is always 800 so it actually same as `dydt[ 800 ] = 0`. which is bigger then 799.

It's looks like that you use numpy arrays in wrong way.

Yes in low level they represents as contiguous array of ints or floats of whatever. But on python level np.array represents as array of arrays. (ie first element as 3d matrix `mtx = np.zeros(shape=[800,400,800]` in python will be `mtx[0][0][0]`)).

So all code after `for i in[N[0]]:` will not work. It tries to access subarray that out of matrix bounds.

UPDATE:

for example you have 3d matrix (3x3x3)

```
 mtx=np.zero(shape=[3,3,3])
 print(mtx) 
 #[ [ [ 0.  0.  0.]
 #    [ 0.  0.  0.]
 #    [ 0.  0.  0.] ]

 #  [ [ 0.  0.  0.]
 #    [ 0.  0.  0.]
 #    [ 0.  0.  0.] ]

 #  [ [ 0.  0.  0.]
 #    [ 0.  0.  0.]
 #    [ 0.  0.  0.] ] ]

 mtx[0] = 1 
 print( mtx )
 #[ [ [ 1.  1.  1.]
 #    [ 1.  1.  1.]
 #    [ 1.  1.  1.] ]

 #  [ [ 0.  0.  0.]
 #    [ 0.  0.  0.]
 #    [ 0.  0.  0.] ]

 #  [ [ 0.  0.  0.]
 #    [ 0.  0.  0.]
 #    [ 0.  0.  0.] ] ]

 mtx[0][1] = 2
 #[ [ [ 1.  1.  1.]
 #    [ 2.  2.  2.]
 #    [ 1.  1.  1.] ]

 # others are zeros

 mtx[0][1][2] = 3
 #[ [ [ 1.  1.  1.]
 #    [ 2.  2.  3.]
 #    [ 1.  1.  1.] ]

 # others are zeros
```

Comment: This means that the syntax: 
     for i in[N[0]]:
          dydt[i] = 0
sets all matrix values = 0, or that the program tries to find more subarrays in the dydt matrix? Sorry, but I am not familiar with Python.

Comment: dydt[i] = 0 will set 2d matrix to 0. for is redundant.

Comment: Great! I have updated my code to:

    L = [8.0, 4.0, 8.0]   # Lenght zones (cm)
    dN = 1.0e2            # Grid points/cm
    N = [int(l*dN) for l in L] # OK!
    lN = N[0] + N[1] + N[2]

with:

    dydt = np.zeros((lN))
which I hope will give i a lNx1 matrix to store my solutions. The equations are updated to not have dydt[N0 - 1] = 0, but from what you explain in your update I wonder if the way I have set up the for-loops only gives the result from the equation of the last loop? Meaning the loops overwrite each other?
Thanks for taking the time to answering!

Comment: They will override each other only if they overlap.  In question   in 4th loop (for example)  (`for i in range(N[0] + 1):`) range will generate numbers from 0 to N[0] (including), It will override first `for` (which run from 0 to N[0] - 2 including), second `for` (which run from N[0]-1 to N[0]-1 including) and third for (which run from N[0] to N[0]). 5th, 6th, 7th and 8th `for` loops will not override any thing from previous loops. But last loop has range from N[0] + N[1] + 2 to N[2]-1  (ie from 1202 to 799) it will override privoius loop in backward order.

Comment: I suppose last loop should be range( N[0] + N[1] + 2, N[0] + N[1] + N[2] - 1 )
(ie from 1202 to 1999) or (N[0] + N[1] + 2, IN-1) (which is same)

Comment: Yes, I figured, so I changed the loops to:
1. range (0, N[0] - 3)
2. in [N[0] - 2]:
3. in [N[0] - 1]
4. in [N[1] - (N[1] - 1)]
5. range (N[1] - (N[1] - 2), N[1] - 3)
6. in [N[1] - 2]
7. in [N[1] - 1]
8. in [N[2] - (N[2] - 1)]
9. range (N[2] - (N[2] - 2), N[2] - 2)
The code runs, but never seem to end. I also run into some trouble with the error message saying "RuntimeError: The array return by func must be one-dimensional, but got ndim=3" once dydt was np.zeros(N).

Comment: Hard to tell what happens with out code, but ranges are still very strange. For example 9th `range(N[2] - (N[2] - 2), N[2] - 2)`  it will be `range( 2, N[2] - 2 )` (ie from 2 to 798 including ), I can't imagine any reason for such complexity (mean N2 - (N2 -2) ).

Comment: Yes, sorry. Updated the loops in the code. 
I did it this way because I got error messages when referencing N[0] + 1 as point number 800 on the grid. I thought I had to set the loop from 0 to 799 in N[0], 0 to 399 in N[2] aso. where N[2] - N[2] - 1 will be point # 800 on the grid, but must be specified as point # 1 in N[2] because of the items in the list.

Comment: "RuntimeError" heppens becouse np.zeros(N)  create 3d matrix (800x400x800 (N0xN1xN2)) but you need 1d matrix (2000 (N0+N1+N2))

Comment: If I understand right, you want to iterate: first in N0 (all 2d matrices) then in N2 (all (some?) 1d matrices). Then for all 1d matrices you need to use 2 for loops (ie `for i in range(0,N[0]-1): for j in range(0, N[1]-1): didt[i][j] = ...` )

Comment: I want to iterate all of N[0], N[1], N[2] in this order, except the to last elements (numbers in N[0], N[1], N[1]) at the end and start of each item (N[0], N[1], N[2]).

Comment: Sorry for all this back and forth, but I've updated the code and would really appreciate it if you could have a look at it.

Comment: Problem is that you create 3d matrix (np.zeros(N)). But you trying to work with it like  if it  is were vector (ie 1d matrix).